# regular expression pattern match excluding a list of cases

Tags: python, regex

I wanna match the street name pattern which consists of several capital case words excluding some cases but I do not know how to do it.

The pattern is "([A-Z][a-z]+ {1,3})" (Let's assume the name of a street consists of 1-3 words) and a short version block list is ["Apt","West","East"] which denotes either direction or room number.

Any word that is in the list("West" for example) should not be in the match result. Words starting with those words in block list however("Westmoreland" for example), should be in the result. How am i gonna write this regular expression?

Comment: Could you please clarify? Add some examples that should match and those that should not. What is the programming language, by the way? Have you already written any code? Please share and let know where you are stuck.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at my question. The entire block list consists of every form of room number and street indicators (Apt, Apartment, Room,rm, N,W,E,NW, West, North, Ave, Blvd Drive and so on). Any word that exact matches the words in the list should not be in the result while words only start with them should be in the list. For example, "West" should not be in the result while "Westmoreland" should. I do these becasue I wanna my re stop when other parts of an physical address comes up.

Comment: I'm using Python re moduel by the way and I only know how to write the capital case part, having no idea how to exclude those words from my  block list .

Comment: here is an example: "Poinsettia Pl Apt" should match "Poinsettia Pl" rather than the entire string

Comment: Have you tried to replace / *\b(Apt|Apartment|Room|rm|ETC.)\b/ (observe the word boundaries) with an empty string? ([see example](https://regex101.com/r/gC7bX6/1))

Comment: I am actually doing US physical address matching from a given text and I know my matching could not cover every case. So I just follow a generally pattern with: StreetNumber (N|W|E|S)? StreetName (Apt|Room)? Location Zipcode. The whole regular expression pattern turns out to be good except there are mistakes in the streetname pattern matching.

Comment: So what do you mean with "the capital case part"?

Comment: I mean words start with a capital letter.

Comment: If you use `([A-Z][a-z]+ {1,3})` as street name, I think you've got to replace it with `([A-Z][a-z]+ ){1,3}`.

Comment: yeah, the problem is how to remove those words from the pattern though

Comment: I still am not sure what input you have and what output you need to get. Try [`\b(?!(?:Apt|West|East)\b)[A-Z][a-z]+(?: (?!(?:Apt|West|East)\b)[A-Z][a-z]+){0,2}`](https://regex101.com/r/wN4mS7/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks! This did work but could u explain why u separate {1,3} to 1 and {0,2}

Comment: @JianxianWu: I explained the expression below.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
\b(?!(?:Apt|West|East)\b)[A-Z][a-z]+(?: (?!(?:Apt|West|East)\b)[A-Z][a-z]+){0,2}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wN4mS7/1)

What I did:

- Fixed your regex to actually match 1 to 3 words: `[A-Z][a-z]+(?: [A-Z][a-z]+){0,2}`
- Added negative lookaheads to restrict the values matched by `[A-Z][a-z]+` parts.

**Expression details**:

- `\b(?!(?:Apt|West|East)\b)[A-Z][a-z]+` - a capital ASCII letter (`[A-Z]`) followed with 1+ ASCII lowercase letters (`[a-z]` but I guess you can also use `[a-zA-Z]+` or `[a-zA-Z]*` here) that are not a whole word `Apt`, `West` or `East` that is made possible with the negative lookahead anchored at the `\b` word boundary. The first `\b` is a leading word boundary, and then the negative lookahead makes sure there are no `Apt`, `West` or `East` right after the word boundary, and before a trailing `\b` word boundary (ensuring a whole word match)
- `(?: (?!(?:Apt|West|East)\b)[A-Z][a-z]+){0,2}` - 0 to 2 occurrences of:

  - - a space
  - `(?!(?:Apt|West|East)\b)[A-Z][a-z]+` - see above. You do not need a leading word boundary here as the `Apt`, `West` or `East` can only appear after a space here, which is a non-word char.

A lot of people would post a shorter solution like

```
(?: ?\b(?!(?:Apt|West|East)\b)[A-Z][a-z]+){1,3}
```

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wN4mS7/2)

However, the optional space at the start would also match this leading space. Morever, the regex does not match linearly now, and that affects performance. With small strings, it is OK, but still it is bad practice.